# Display scrollbar after using webkit-scrollbar{ display: none }

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

In my project, we have a common css file and in which, we use `webkit-scrollbar{ display: none }` to hide scroll bar in chrome, but in some page, we need to display scroll bar in chrome. I have tried some way I have found on internet. Ex: `display: block, initial` ,... or `all : unset`, but it doesn't work.
Anyone have any idea for this problem ? Thanks

Comment: related to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll

Comment: @NajmiehSadatSafarabadi : It doesn't related to the topic you have mentioned, I need to override webkit-scrollbar{ display: none } in chrome to display scrollbar, not to hide scroll bar like your topic you have mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Try using `::-webkit-scrollbar { visibility: visible; }` on those pages where you want the scroll to appear.

Comment: Thank, but it doesn't work

Comment: @QUANGTuấnVũ I've updated the answer, please have a look